# how to create a wait job in informatica

Tags: wait, polling, informatica

My requirement is to create a job in informatica which will run for every 15 min and look for a status column in abc table.If it is “Approved” THEN  It will  exit and kick off the rest of the  jobs.

If the status is not approved it will not do anything and run after 15 min.This process wil continue until we have a approval status.

So, No matter what happens in the above two scenarios,This process will run in every 15 minutes.

I have worked on the same requirement in unix using loops and conditional statments but I am not sure how this can be achieved using informatica.Could you please help me on this.

Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding a scheduler that runs every 15 minutes.  The best way that I've found to "loop" sessions in Informatica is:

1. run the session once, check if it failed using conditional links
2. if it did fail, run a timer task for an amount of time (a minute, an hour, whatever)
3. then try to run the same session again by copying and pasting the session up ahead of the timer task, and repeat a few times as necessary.

So if you added a scheduler into the mix, you could set the scheduler to have the workflow run every 15 minutes, and have the timer tasks halt the workflow for 4 or 5 minutes each.  Then you could use `SESSSTARTTIME` function in some pre/post-session task to determine when the scheduler will fire off again and simply abort the workflow before that time.